# Adding a contact to Outlook with only the email domain (no username)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am trying to create a general contact for our outgoing fax which our office does through an internet client where the fax number is inputted as the username (e.g. 5555551234@faxplace.com). I am looking to add it as a contact to the address book, but with only the domain of the email and not a specific username attached to it (e.g. @faxplace.com vs. 5555551234@faxplace.com).

Is this possible with Outlook?

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is your mail server? Exchange server?

I have done a test in my exchange server and outlook, following this [guidance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-contact-in-outlook-1ef8f35b-04be-4bd0-ac9c-6d6a146887ce) I can add this users as contacts for specific mailboxes but these contacts cannot appear in address book, since if you want to add users in address book, you should add contacts in exchange server side not outlook side.